# getting LC is not defined in literallycanvas

Tags: javascript, ionic3

literallyCanvas works fine with ionic 3 in (browser and android) but gives `Can't find variable: LC` error while building ionic 3 ios app with xcode.

In my index.html i have added

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js">`

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js" ></script>`
`<script src="assets/static/js/literallycanvas.js"></script>`

and in my wbBoard.ts file i have declared literallyCanvas as

`declare const LC: any;`
when i am trying to
`console.log(LC)`
i am a getting an error which says `Can't find variable: LC`

Comment: Any code sample or more context could be very helpful.

Comment: I have added sample code regarding the issue i am facing.